# Correct Partition table not showing when iinstalling Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, operating-systems

My current OS is Windows 10.I am installing Ubuntu 17.04 from pendrive. When I run Ubuntu in TRY MODE(without installing) then it shows all partitions- sda2,3,4,5 
[You can see the screenshot]
[image: Showing all the partitions sda2,3,4,5]

But when I the run the installer then the partition sda 5 is not visible,and also the size of all partitions change.[SEE SCREENSHOT][[image: Not showing the partitions when I run the installer]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD7yN.jpg)

I don't want to lose the data from sda3,4,5. I am ready to delete data from /dev/sda2 because it has only windows on it.
Why correct partioning is not showing? Do I need to use any tool for that? All type of solutions are welcome. Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I follow a different way for installing Ubuntu alongside windows. I,

1. First un-allocate space in windows machine, by making free space from an existing partion. It is done through Disk management.
2. Then I use the un-allocated space for installing the new Linux-OS. It will be shown as freespace in the partition table. Do confirm how much memory u have un-allocated in windows and use the corresponding freespace, like for 51200mb(50gb) unallocated memory u can see somewhere near to 51200mb(50gb) of freespace during linux installation.

Any way I follow the [itsFOSS](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) page for installing the Ubuntu alongside windows. It always worked for me.

Comment: I liked the approach you are talking about but I am not trying to install alongside. I want to remove Windows 10 and at that place I want Ubuntu. @Zarak1

Comment: I think you can answer my question well because you have chosen a very well approach. So please see my above comment and tell in case I want to replace Windows with Ubuntu